# The notion of smoothness for maps defined on cartesian product of two sets

Tags: lie-groups, smooth-manifolds

I have just started reading about Lie groups and by definition (at least the way it is defined in my class),

> A group G is a Lie group if it is a smooth manifold and the map $G \times G \ni (g,h) \mapsto gh^{-1} \in G$ is smooth.

I am not comfortable with the notion of smoothness here. Moreover, if you want a specific problem where I am stuck, in my class notes, it is written that "this definition implies that the inverse map $G \ni h \mapsto h^{-1} \in G$ is smooth and this follows from the fact that $G \times G \ni (e,h) \mapsto eh^{-1} \in G$ is smooth ($e$ is the identity element of G).

Here's where exactly I am stuck in trying to prove the above statement. Consider the maps I have mentioned above excluding the one in definition. Call the first map $i$, the second map $f$ and define a third map $g$ which takes $G \ni h \mapsto (e,h) \in G \times G$. It can be seen that $i=f \circ g$ and if I can prove smoothness of $g$, then I am done.

To show smoothness of $g$ at a point $h$ on the smooth manifold $G$, I take a chart $(U,\phi)$ of $G$ such that $h \in U$. Then I take a chart $(U' \times V, \phi ' \times \psi)$ of $G \times G$ such that $g(U) \subset U' \times V$. Now to show smoothness, I have to show that the map $(\phi ' \times \psi) \circ g \circ \phi ^{-1}: \phi (U) \subset \Bbb{R}^n \to \Bbb{R}^m \times \Bbb{R}^p \supset \phi ' (U') \times \psi(V) $ is smooth. I am clueless now. How do I proceed?

Answer (score 1):

> **Lemma.** Let $X,Y$ be $C^n$ manifolds for $n\in\{\omega, \infty, 0,1,\ldots\}$. Let $y_0\in Y$ and $f:X\to X\times Y$ be given by $f(x)=(x,y_0)$. Then $f$ is $C^n$.

*Proof.* Let $x_0\in X$ and consider a chart $(U,\phi)$ around $x_0$ in $X$. Now consider any chart $(V,\theta)$ around $y_0$ in $Y$. Then we have the chart $(U\times V, \phi\times\theta)$ around $(x_0,y_0)$ in $X\times Y$. With this we have

$$f(U)=U\times\{y_0\}\subseteq U\times V$$
$$(\phi\times\theta)\circ f\circ \phi^{-1}(v)=\big(v,\theta(y_0)\big)$$

i.e. the composition is the product of identity and constant map which is easily seen to be $C^n$.

Note that the domain of the composition is some open subset of $\mathbb{R}^s$ (i.e. $\phi(U)$) while the codomain is $\mathbb{R}^s\times\mathbb{R}^t$ where $s=\dim X$ and $t=\dim Y$. $\Box$

Comment: I am not able to understand why RHS of the last equation is $(x,y_0)$. The first element of the tuple will be $x$ because there is $\phi(\phi^{-1})$ in there, but shouldn't the second element be $\theta(y_0)$? And if you have taken $\theta$ to be a constant map, then it is no longer injective and thus not a chart map. Thank you.

Comment: @NiketParikh Right, it was a typo, it was supposed to be $\theta(y_0)$. The point is that the second argument is independent of $x$, i.e. constant. And $\theta$ is not a constant map, indeed! Charts can only be constant if we are dealing with $0$-dimensional manifolds.

Comment: If I get you correctly, I don’t understand why the composition of the three functions is the same as the function $id \times K$ on $X \times Y$ , where $K(y)=\theta (y_0)$ for all $y$.

Comment: @NiketParikh Almost. Not on $X\times Y$ but on open subsets of $\mathbb{R}^s$. I've update the answer. That's the whole point. In order to deal with smoothness we have to somehow go to $\mathbb{R}^n$, where this notion is easier to grasp.

Comment: Ah yes. Sorry for the confusion in the last comment; I had pressed enter by mistake. Can I talk with you on chat? I have a few questions and it might get a little long here.

Comment: @NiketParikh Sorry, I'm a bit busy. Feel free to ask another question on math exchange.

Comment: No problem. Thank you.